# Disable background panel in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I have these three panels in `layeredPane2` as `backPanel` , `overlayPanel` and `popupPanel`. When I click the button I want that only the `popupPanel` (The one with "task created!" is visible), along with the `overlayPanel` the gray full size box that is supposed to hide the `backPanel`.This the starting screen with only `backPanel` visible.[image]

when I click the `createBtn`, I get this:
[image]

In top left corner, I don't why but there is the button and the text field visible. Also, the `Create` button doesn't hide. Moreover, the elements on the `backPanel` are accessible like this:
[image: I can enter the text in the textField]

This is my code:

```
popupPanel.setVisible(true);
overlayPanel.setVisible(true);
```

I tried `backPanel.setFocusable(false);` , but that doesn't help.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**

```
tfTitle.requestFocusInWindow();
        taDesc.setLineWrap(true);
        taDesc.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        overlayPanel.setBackground(new Color(20,20,20, 150));
        overlayPanel.setVisible(false);
        layeredPane2.moveToFront(popupPanel);
        layeredPane2.moveToBack(backPanel);
        popupPanel.setVisible(false);
```

Elements' Hierarchy -

[image]

Comment: ```jButton3 ``` is the blue tick on the ```popupPanel```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer the questions about the stray and visible objects without seeing your component hierarchy. This is only part of the answer.

I assume you have a panel with an `OverlayLayout`. It's a common trap how the layer Z position should be specified:

```
add(popupPanel, 800); // Doesn't work
add(popupPanel, Integer.valueOf(800)); // Works
```

You can prevent clickthrough to lower panels in this way:

```
// Prevent click-through to lower layers
popupPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseInputAdapter() { });
```

If you, additionally, want to close the panel when the user clicks on the darkened region outside the panel, it instead becomes like this:

```
MouseListener closeAdapter = new MouseInputAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ignored) {
        popupPanel.setVisible(false);
    }
};
popupPanel.addMouseListener(closeAdapter);

// Prevent click-through to lower layers
taskCreatedPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseInputAdapter() { });
```

Comment: At the moment I am using free design as layout.

Comment: I've added component hierarchy in the question. Thanks!

Comment: You must use `OverlayLayout` in order to have a defined Z ordering of it's direct children. And which is the dark background?

Comment: Since there were only three panels, and I am using Layered Pane, so I just used moveToFront and moveToBack for ordering.

Comment: The dark background is actually the overlayPanel, which is visible once the user clicks "Create" button

Comment: I suggest making overlayPanel part of the popupPanel, by renaming popupPanel to taskCreatedPanel and nesting it inside overlayPanel, and then renaming overlayPanel to popupPanel. That way my code snippets fits your gui.

Comment: The click-through thing worked, but there is still the create button and text field visible on top left (like in second image), and the create button doesn't hide as well.

Comment: I just noticed Netbeans' GUI Buidler doesn't allow you to set the Z ordering of components in OverlayLayout, so you may have to do it manually. The way I build my GUI is to put every panel in a separate GUI Builder JPanel and make the frame by hand.

Comment: I haven't as such specified any z ordering, but just used moveToFront and moveToBack methods of the layered pane in Free Design as layout